# Eclipse Gradle Plugin: adding dependencies automatically like Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle

I read that Gradle combines the best of Maven and Ant so I'm trying it.

I already installed the best integrated Gradle Plugin for Eclipse according to the Gradle webpage. It is the plugin made by the SpringSource STS team. I can create a "New Project -> Gradle Project" easily just with this plugin installed.

**With the plugin m2e, a Maven Plugin for Eclipse, searching and adding dependencies automatically is easy. Is it possible to do the same with Gradle? How?**

Thank you in advance :)

Carlos

UPDATE:
It is very easy to install and configure Gradle in Eclipse following the instructions I wrote in my blog: http://estiloasertivo.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/tutorial-howto-install-and-configure.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automatically searching and adding dependencies isn't yet supported by the Eclipse Gradle tooling. I recommend to use http://search.maven.org to find the dependency to add, and then copy the dependency information listed under "Grails" into the `dependencies` block of the build script.

Comment: The Chrome plugin is really handy too

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to know your opinion. Right now, do you prefer Maven or Gradle?

Comment: As one of the developers of Gradle, I'm obviously biased.

Comment: `apply plugin: 'eclipse'`, `compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '12.0'` (retrieved from Guava website), and `build eclipse` did exactly what I wanted.  New to Gradle, very slick!  (I guess this question was for bypassing the manual retrieval of the dependency info?  I can deal with that!)